# Regarding Logic and Reductio Ad Absurdum

Tags: logic

If I know that proposition A is true, can I perform a reductio ad absurdum this way (I know it sounds redundant but humour me for a moment):

> Assume ~A.
>
> This leads to the contradiction ~A & A, because we know A is true.
>
> Therefore, conclude the negation of the assumption: A

I have a specific case in mind. Let A = "God exists." Let B = "It's possible that God exists."
Assume ~A.
Contradiction: ~A & B (because B is true (we are not hard atheists here)).
Therefore A.

In fact it seems anything that is unknown can be proven this way, so there must be a problem with it.

I'm thinking that the propositions used in the contradiction must arise from calculations derived from the assumption. They cannot arise from anywhere external. Do you reckon that's right?

Comment: NO; you do not know that **A** is *true*: you want to prove it.

Comment: We assume **not-A** and we derive a contradiction whatever; thus, we are licensed to conclude that the assumption is wrong.

Comment: Ok so you're saying that if you know that A is true, you cannot use a reductio ad absurdum in this way? You cannot assume anything that contradicts A?

Comment: If **A** is *true*, no sound logical system would derive a contradiction from it. If so, with the same inference rule as above, we would be licensed to conclude **not-A**. But we know that **not-A** is *false* !

Comment: But you are saying "if you know that **A** is true, you cannot use a *reductio ad absurdum* in this way? You cannot assume anything that contradicts **A** ?" YES, we can assume **not-A** and we have immediately a contradicition. Thus, we conclude with the negation of the assumption, i.e. **not-not-A** that (in *classical* logic) it is again **A**.

Comment: Ok so what about this example. A=it will rain tomorrow B=it is possible that it will rain tomorrow. And note ~A->~B (if it will not rain tomorrow then it is not possible that it will rain tomorrow) ok now look at a reductio ad absurdum: Assume ~A, then ~B is also true, but it *is* actually true that B (because it is possible that it will rain tomorrow) so I have a contradiction, B&~B, so I can assert the negation of the assumption (~A), ie ~~A=A, can you pls tell me where I went wrong? Is my mistake that I asserted that it is possible that it will rain today after assuming that it would not?

Comment: You are changing the game :-) The first example has been discussed already above, and it is not "useful". The second one (discussed below about God) is different and **is** formally valid. "From **¬A → ¬B,  B** and **¬A** we can correctly prove by *Reductio* **A**".

Comment: If we have correctly proved that A, then we have proved that it will rain tomorrow. Which is silly, we don't know if it will rain tomorrow.

Comment: Last try: we have proved **A**: "it will rain tomorrow" under some assumptions. Specifically, under the assumption **B**: "it is possible that it will rain tomorrow" **and** the assumption: **¬A → ¬B** that is equiv to  **B → A** "if it is possible that it will rain tomorrow, then it will rain tomorrow", which is quite debatable.

Comment: But formally **is**valid: if we agree that "it is possible that..." and that "if it is possible..., then it will rain", then it is valid to conclude with "it will rain".

Comment: I see two issues here: 1) define the word 'possible' in a logically consistent way and apply that definition to something simple like "it's possible the die will come up reading 6"; 2) existence is not a valid predicate, at least in mathematics. Formally, if you say "there exists x such that...", you must include a set to contain x. In other words "there exists x in S such that...". See if you can still phrase your God argument using that formality ("exists in our mind" is different "exists in the observable universe").

Comment: A contradiction is never between A and B, but must be between A and not-A where one is true, one is false and there is no third alternative. Aristotle is clear about this but philosophers often less so. .

Answer (score 1):

The first argument simply proves A from the assumption of A. It is not surprising that one can do that or that it is valid! Philosophers call it "begging the question."

The second argument is not the same argument. It tries to employ not-A and B as a contradiction. But that is not a formal contradiction, as that must be some sentence and the negation of that same sentence.

Neither can be used to prove any old sentence. The first argument proves any A, yes, but *only given the assumption that A is true*!

It is not a restriction of standard first order logic that the sentences come from anywhere in particular. For example, if an argument has a contradiction in its premises, that contradiction can be employed in reasoning from them toward a conclusion.

Comment: For the second argument, what about this way ~A -> ~B (If god doesn't exist, it's not possible that God exists).... so the contradiction could be ~B and B which leads to the conclusion that A. I can't see where the problem with this is. I tried looking at modal logic, but that didn't help. Took A = God exists, Took 'it is possible that God exists = God exists in some possible world, and the logic of the argument worked out, but I don't think 'it is possible that God exists' is the same as 'God exists in some possible world'.

Comment: You would have to spell out what the premises and conclusions are in this new formulation, as opposed to what is proof strategy. I am not at all sure I'm understanding your suggestion.

Comment: A=God exists B=it is possible that God exists
~A->~B (if God does not exist, then it is not possible that he exists)
Then formulate an absurdity from the assumption that God does not exist ~A
Since ~A->~B, we can say ~B but then at the same time, B is true because it is possible that Gor exists, so B&~B is a contradiction, therefore A, if The God example doesn't suit, just think of anything that is possible, like 'it will rain tomorrow' and 'it is possible that it will rain tomorrow', hopefully this clears it up

Comment: @RobHv - Assumptions: (i)  **¬A → ¬B**; (ii) **B**; (iii) **¬A**; thus, by *Modus Ponens* with (iii) and (i) we have: (iv) **¬B**: contradiction ! Thus, by *Reductio*, we conclude with (v)  **¬¬A**, i.e. with **A**: "God exists". The proof is formally valid; to say that it concludes... it depends on our "belief" in the assumptions (i) and (ii). In particular, what about (i) "if God does not exist, then it is not possible that he exists" ?

Comment: (i) **¬A → ¬B** is equivalent to **B → A** : "if it is possible that God exists, then he exists" that seems a "variant" of the well-known definition of "necessary Being".

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see these comments!! Thanks heaps Mauro!! What a great name, I used to know a guy named Mauro he was bald n very tall. =)

Comment: Hmm it is quite a brilliant answer, thank you. But intuitively I'm still thinking that if God does not exist then it is not possible that he exists..

Comment: The limitation of working from a premise that is intuitive to you but not generally accepted is that your argument will be persuasive at most to those who agree with that premise, and others will shrug and ignore. If it helps you see an interesting implication of a view you hold, however, it's worthwhile work!

Comment: @RobHv "if banana flavoured beer doesn't exist, it's impossible for banana flavoured beer to exist", "if a 13 stringed banjo doesn't exist, then it is not possible for a 13 stringed banjo to exist". 

The point I'm making is that, while it may or may not be true that it's impossible for god to exist, it doesn't *follow* from the statement "God does not exist".  So, regardless of whether the statement "it is not possible for God to exist" is true, the statement "if God does not exist then it is not possible for God to exist" is false.

Comment: perhaps the confusion came from the phrasing "if god does not exist then it is not possible *that he* exists", when it should really be "*for him to exist*" or "that he *might* exist", or "then god can't exist" etc. but that's an English language problem rather than a formal logic one.